# Enviar um dado para o banco com node js

Tags: node.js, api, rest

Estou criando uma REST API, mas to com dificuldade em enviar um dado para o banco de dados usando 3 modulos, deixe eu mostrar meu codigo

rotaCliente.js nesta rota eu recebo um json com email,nome,senha e cpf 
e mando para o modulo controladorCliente.

```
const controladorCliente = require('../controladores/controladorCliente');
const db = require('../../config/config.js');

module.exports = function(app){
    app.post('/clientes', (req,res) => {
        controladorCliente.criarcliente(req.body)
        .then(resposta => {
            res.send(resposta)
        });
    });
}
```

Aqui é o modulo controlador cliente... No controlador cliente eu pego todos os dados em json, e chamo um modulo chamado UsuarioDao que coloca esses dados na tabela usuario e me retorna o id do usuario criado. Dai então eu chamo o modulo ClienteDao e coloco esse id na tabela cliente, o problema esta ai, eu nao consigo colocar o dado nesta tabela usando essa divisao em 3 modulos, nao consegui copiar do salvar de usuario pois ele usa apenas a rota que ja chama direto o DAO.

```
const db = require('../../config/config.js');
const ClienteDao = require('../dao/ClienteDao');
const clienteDao = new UsuarioDao(db.cliente);

const UsuarioDao = require('../dao/UsuarioDao');
const usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao(db.usuario);

module.exports.criarCliente = function(novoCliente){
    idUsuario = 0
    var usuario = {
        "nome" :novoCliente.nome,
        "email":novoCliente.email,
        "cpf"  :novoCliente.cpf,
        "senha":novoCliente.senha

    }

    usuarioDao.criarUsuario(usuario)
        .then(resposta => {
            idUsuario = resposta[0].id;
        });

    var cliente = {
        "id_usuario": isUsuario
    }

    return  clienteDao.criarCliente(cliente)
    .then(resultado =>resultado )
    .catch(erro => erro);              
}
```

Comment: Não entendi, o problema está em salvar clientes ou usuários? Mostra algum erro no console? Tem certeza que `resposta[0].id` retorna o valor correto?

Comment: o problema está em salvar clientes, nao mostra erro no console, diz apenas que nao conseguiu fazer o metodo post, e sim resposta[0].id retorna o id.Obrigado